# How to make seperate lines with c# (Textfile)

Tags: c#, split, streamreader, readline

I'm making this application for fun but i have a problem

I want this string/file to be read in seperate lines.

this the file(not the whole file):

```
1ChampSelectPack.Ahri.mp31ChampSelectPack.Akali.mp31ChampSelectPack.Alistar.mp31ChampSelectPack.Amumu.mp31ChampSelectPack.Anivia.mp31ChampSelectPack.Annie.mp31ChampSelectPack.Ashe.mp31ChampSelectPack.Blitzcrank.mp31ChampSelectPack.Brand.mp31ChampSelectPack.Caitlyn.mp3
```

and this is what i got so far:

```
            List<SoundPath> paths = new List<SoundPath>();
            StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("C:/Users/Esat/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/WikiLoL/WikiLoL/lolSoundBoard/1ChampSelectPack/files.txt");

            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {

                SoundPath path = new SoundPath();
                path.Path = reader.ReadLine();
                paths.Add(path);
            }

            reader.Close();

            return paths;
```

Comment: how do you want them to be seperated?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if that is what you want:

```
"YourString".Split(new string[] {"mp3"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

You would have to append the "mp3" on each line afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using splitting on .mp3 and adding .mp3 in each element of resultant array.

```
string text = File.ReadAllText("C:/Users/Esat/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/WikiLoL/WikiLoL/lolSoundBoard/1ChampSelectPack/files.txt");
string[] lines = text.Split(new string[] { ".mp3" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    lines[i] = lines[i] + ".mp3";
```